# Maintaining Selection State in KendoGrid Across Page Transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In kendoGrid, when the page loads, Assuming I already have the selected productID. So, when the grid is loaded and the data is bound, it selects the corresponding row.

The problem arises when I uncheck the product ID on the first page, then navigate to the second page to check the data. Upon returning to the first page, I notice that the previously unchecked product ID has become checked again.

I want the grid to fetch and display only the IDs that I have actively selected, ensuring that my selections persist across different pages and actions. Appreciate your help..

[DEMO IN DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/Alipevuw)

```html
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  dataBound: function(e){
    var grid = this;
    var rows = grid.items();
    $(rows).each(function(e) {
      var row = this;
      var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);
      if (selectedProductIDs.includes(dataItem.ProductID)) {
        grid.select(row);
      }                    
    });
  },
  dataSource: dataSourceTEST,
  pageable: true,
  persistSelection: true,
  sortable: true,
  change: function(e) {
    console.log("The selected product ids are: [" + this.selectedKeyNames().join(", ") + "]");
  },
  columns: [{
    selectable: true,
    width: "50px"
  },
            {
              field: "ProductName",
              title: "Product Name"
            },
            {
              field: "UnitPrice",
              title: "Unit Price",
              format: "{0:c}"
            },
            {
              field: "UnitsInStock",
              title: "Units In Stock"
            },
            {
              field: "Discontinued"
            }
           ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a somewhat similar error, it happened that when I selected an item in the kendo grid, and turned the page, when I returned the selection from the previous page no longer persisted, not even by adding the .PersistSelection()...
I have chosen not to use columns.select() and in my kendo grid I can do the following:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.JoinContractID).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' id='eachCheckbox-#= Contract_Join.ContractID #' onchange='saveCheckedItem(this);' class='chkbx'/>").Title("Select").Editable("ReturnFalse").Width(80).Filterable(false).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center" });
```

Then I added the following event:

```
.Events(events => events.DataBound("onDataBoundGridJoin"))
```

And my js

```
var selectItems = [];
function saveCheckedItem(element) {
    if (element.checked) {
        selectItems.push(element.id);
    }
    else {
        if (selectItems.includes(element.id)) {
            var removePosition = selectItems.indexOf(element.id);
            selectItems.splice(removePosition, 1);
        }
    }
}
function onDataBoundGridJoin(e) {
    selectItems.forEach((checkId, index) => {
        $(`#${checkId}`).prop("checked", true);
    })
}
function ReturnFalse(e) {
    return false;
}
```

maybe it will work for you too, good luck